# Attempting to draw a sprite in libgdx and nothing appears

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, and i dont know what the problem is...I can draw animations for some reason, but if i try to draw a simple static texture, nothing. I just want to draw a sprite at given coordinates and have a box2d body for collisions. I can get the body to work too, just not the texture. right now, I am trying to rebuild the whole thing, but still no progress. my object is

```
public class RoadBlock extends Sprite {
    private TextureAtlas atlas;

    public RoadBlock (PlayScreen screen, float x, float y) {
        atlas = new 
        TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("tunnelPics/tunnelAtlas.atlas"));
        setPosition(x, y);
        setRegion(atlas.findRegion("barbSmol"), 0, 0, 120, 75);
    }
    public void draw(Batch batch) {super.draw(batch);}
}
```

In the level it's drawn as

```
public void render(MyGdxGame game){
    for(Sprite RB: RBs) {
        RB.draw(game.batch);
    }
}
```

this populates RB (an arrayList) from the tiled TMX map objects that relate to the sprites.

then in when rendering in the playScreen, i use

```
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);
    //background color
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND); //enable transparent images
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //render
    renderer.render();
    game.batch.enableBlending(); 
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    //render character
    player.draw(game.batch);
    //render current level
    curLevel.render(game);
    game.batch.end();
}
```

this calls the render function from above.

Comment: How you create `RoadBlock` object ?

Comment: Need more info on how `RoadBlock` is instantiated and also how `curlLevel` is set.